# Change "Open With" from terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, file, defaults

How do I change the default program to open a file on Mac? For example, I want docx-files to be opened with Word 2011 instead of Word 2019.

Comment: I was just going to link to that too, but I'm not sure how it will work for what is essentially the same app, just different versions; usually the newer app wins.